# How to pass data from mapped objects to its parent component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a shopping cart app, the app includes each item as a card component. I rendered these cards by mapping some dummy object data like this:

```js
const Home = () => {
  const dummyData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'tshirt',
      price: 10
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'coat',
      price: 20
    }
  ]
  
  const RenderCards = () => {
    return (
      dummyData.map(
        (d) => {
          return (
            <Card key={d.id} title={d.title} price={d.price} handleAddToCart={handleAddToCart}/>
          )
        }
      )
    )
  }
  
  const handleAddToCart = () => {
    // maybe access id and price here?
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <RenderCards />
    </>
  )
}
```

and the `Card` component being rendered:

```js
const Card = ({id, title, price}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div key={id}>
        <p>{title}</>
        <p>{price}</>
        <button onClick={handleAddToCart}>Add to cart</button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Now on click of the button in each card, I'd like to send the data (the id of the card and the price of the item) back to the parent `Home` component. Say 2nd card is clicked, I want to have access to `id` and `price` in `Home`.

**EDIT:**
Maybe I didn't make myself clear, I'd like to access the clicked card's price and id in `handleAddToCart` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either pass the handler down and have the child pass the details to it, like this:

```
items.map(item => <Item addToCart={addToCart} {...item} />)

const Item = ({ id, name, addToCart }) => 
  <div>
    {name}
    <button onClick={() => addToCart(id)}>Add to Cart</button>
  </div>
```

Or pass down a values-included callback like this:

```
items.map(item => <Item addToCart={() => handleAddToCart(item.id)} {...item} />)

const Item = ({ id, name, addToCart }) => 
  <div>
    {name}
    <button onClick={addToCart}>Add to Cart</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: For 1st approach, how should I access `id` in `addToCart` function in Home component?

Comment: I think there is 1 thing you didn't mention: in order to access `id` in `addToCart`, the `addToCart` function needs to take `id` as an input parameter.

Comment: @thinkvantagedu Yes, if you need the `id` in your `addToCart` function (which is the assumption in my example code), then you need it to have access to that ID.

Answer (score 0):

In `<Home />` component, first you can introduce a new state with `useState` as:

```
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null)
```

Then pass down through props the `setSelectedItem` in order to be able to trigger there:

```
<Card key={d.id} title={d.title} price={d.price} handleAddToCart={handleAddToCart}
      setSelectedItem={setSelectedItem} />
```

Then in `<Card />` component use as:

```
const Card = ({id, title, price, setSelectedItem}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div key={id}>
        <p>{title}</>
        <p>{price}</>
        <button onClick={() => {
            handleAddToCart();
            setSelectedItem({ id, title, price});
        }}>Add to cart</button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

**+1 suggestion:**

I would pass down to `<Card />` component the details in one attribute as:

```
<Card key={d.id}
      data={d}
      handleAddToCart={handleAddToCart}
      setSelectedItem={setSelectedItem} />
```

Then destructure inside as:

```
const Card = (props) => {
   const { data, setSelectedItem, handleAddToCart } = props
   const { id, title, price } = data

   // more code
}
```